# Setting at job with shortcode not working

Tags: php, posts, plugin-development

```
function set_server_jobs() {
  $permalink = 'https://www.jameswestpaintings.net/about/';
  $auction_end_delayed = '15:40';
$curl_command = 'curl ' . $permalink . ' | at ' . $auction_end_delayed;
shell_exec("'" . $curl_command . "'");
  echo $curl_command;
}
add_shortcode('test_curl', 'set_server_jobs');
```

Code runs with no errors and echoed command runs properly from bash command line when tested.

However, the bash command is not transferring to the server on page load and executing. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Check if `shell_exec` is enabled in your `php.ini`.

Comment: Try using the [Execution Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) instead of `shell_exec`, also check if your PHP is running in `safe mode`. `shell_exec` is **disabled** in safe mode.

Comment: Did both of those...it IS enabled and using backticks per the manual yielded same result.

Comment: Running Php 7 btw.